# Muted youtube video on random time point

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm looking for a way to mute and unmute 2 embed youtube videos on random time points or intervals. But the muting and unmuting must happen in turns and simultaneously, so youtube video 1 is muted and youtube video 2 is unmuted, youtube video 1 unmuted and youtube video 2 muted.It goes on like that. Any suggestions on that?
Thank you!

Comment: Exactly in what part are you having difficulties?

Comment: I made this so you can see how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/638ty5za/

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the thing I've been trying to do. Sorry a newbie here. Can you explain the value *5000 + 2000? Because I'm trying to make the muting more frequent and shorter

Comment: @GiangNguyenHoang I used `Math.random() * 5000 + 2000` as the timeout delay. Basically, this means that the delay will be a random value between 2 seconds and 7 seconds (5+2). If you wanted a value between 1 and 3 seconds, you would do `Math.random() * 2000 + 1000`. http://jsfiddle.net/yLsa320j/

Comment: @blex Thanks. I've googled the Math.random(). I'm thinking of doing something similar with the visual so the final product would look like an automatic video collage. Any clues how to do that?

Comment: You could hide the player as you mute it, and show it as you unmute it. In the following example, I use a CSS class to do that, and I apply/remove that class with JS: http://jsfiddle.net/n47016t3/ Important: You need to hide the player either by setting its opacity to 0, or by moving it out of the screen (which is what I did), and not by using `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`, because that will prevent the player from working correctly while it is hidden.